# EFFICIENTLY Load classes from jar file INSIDE jar file

Tags: java, plugins, urlclassloader

Java programmer here.

I'm trying to make a "plugin system" in java, and I would like ot make it so that the user can import their own java libraries if they needed to so they are not limited to only have my plugin loading application in their build path.

I was planning on allowing the user to make a folder called "lib" in their project, which is where they would put all the other libraries they needed, so they can then add those to the build path with the application erroring when loading all the necessary plugins. But, I am having trouble to do so.

Here is an example plugin jar file I have, that is structured the way I want it to be:

```
Plugin.jar
    |---org
        |---pluginpackage
            |---PluginMainClass.class
    |---lib
        |---user-lib.jar
            |---libpackage
                |---InterfaceA.class
                |---ClassB.class
                |---...
    |---plugin-description.xml
```

What I was wondering is this: What would be the most efficient way to load all the libraries the user has loaded inside the "lib" folder?

This is the current code I have, but it takes longer than desired to load the libraries:

```
private void readLibraryInJar(JarInputStream jarLibraryInputStream, File dirOut) throws IOException {
        if (jarLibraryInputStream == null)
            return;

        JarEntry entry = null;

        while ((entry = jarLibraryInputStream.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
            final String jarPath = entry.getName().trim();

            if (jarPath.endsWith(".class")) {

                File f = new File(dirOut, jarPath);

                if (!f.exists()) {
                    if (!f.getParentFile().exists()) {
                        f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    }
                    f.createNewFile();

                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 100];

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);

                int len;

                while ((len = jarLibraryInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                out.close();

            }
        }
}
```

The above code reads each class file inside the desired library and copy's its content's into a new file. I know that a more efficient way is out there somewhere (e.g. Apache Tomcat project can have a "lib" folder), so I was wondering if I could load the library jar file more effeciently than I currently do (planning on using URLClassLoader to load it, so if you could transform it into a URL that would be awesome, but if that is impossible, I am still okay with any way more efficient than my current one.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to unpack a JAR that is itself in a JAR without extracting the contents from the outer JAR first

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to do it. Thanks anyways.